# GUI development with Python

Tags: python, user-interface

I want to BUILD a client-side app with Python (ex: Atom Text-Editor). However, I do not want to use Tkinter, I prefer to know how to write it from scratch, or some decent frameworks for doing so

Comment: Ok, you're sharing your plans with us. Do you have a question?

Comment: What happens when you enter the title of your question into a search engine?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use wxPython if you want to avoid Tkinter. PyQt is also an option.